# Zxing под VC++ 2008 ошибка error LNK2019

Tags: c++

Всем привет
Собираю приложение на VC 2008 по декодированию штрих кода  на Zxing (сама поддержка библиотеки на С++ прекращена почти год назад...комментариев уже никто не даст на code.google и на github из разрабочиков ), но очень надо...На .net все работает без проблем.
Код типа:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "zxing/Result.h"
//#include "zxing/Reader.h"
#include "zxing/common/GreyscaleLuminanceSource.h"
#include "zxing/oned/MultiFormatOneDReader.h"
#include "zxing/DecodeHints.h"
#include "zxing/common/HybridBinarizer.h"
#include "zxing/BinaryBitmap.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace zxing;
..........
int i32_width;
int i32_height;
zxing::ArrayRef<char> pu8_l_pointer;

/*... и так далее по примерам на первом же с пользовании*/
Ref<LuminanceSource> source( new GreyscaleLuminanceSource(pu8_l_pointer,i32_width,i32_height,0,0,i32_width,i32_height));
```

В последней строке ошибка:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external
> symbol "public: __thiscall
> zxing::GreyscaleLuminanceSource::GreyscaleLuminanceSource(class
> zxing::ArrayRef<char>,int,int,int,int,int,int)"
> (??0GreyscaleLuminanceSource@zxing@@QAE@V?$ArrayRef@D@1@HHHHHH@Z)
> referenced in function _wmain

Не нравиться GreyscaleLuminanceSource.h из исходников. В чем причина понять не могу.

Comment: вы добавили в линковку используемую вами библиотеку?

Comment: Ошибка линкера говорит, что не реализован какой-то метод, это может быть не только из-за того, что написал предшественник, дайте полностью код ошибки.